# Routed controller page not found with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users"
map.resources :users
```

and /account/new points to /users/new just fine.

However, if I add a new page, payment.html.erb, in /app/views/user, restart the server, and visit /account/payment, I get

```
No route matches "/account/payment" with {:method=>:get}
```

/users/payment does show the payment page, though.

Why is the route not working for /account/payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use RESTful routes you have to manually add them to your routing, like so:

```
map.resource :account, :controller => "users", :collection => { :payment => :get }
```

More info at the [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Comment: With a singleton resource, you're not going to have the :collection option.  You'd have to use :member.